# PySpark error while joining dfs: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrames which are the same schema:

```
>>> df
DataFrame[created_at: timestamp, modified: timestamp, status: string, shipment_count: int, eta_cal: decimal(10,2), eta_cal_uofm: string, eta_cal_name: string, origin_day_of_week: smallint, eta_head_id: int, exception_reason: string, id: bigint]
>>> df_latest
DataFrame[created_at: timestamp, modified: timestamp, status: string, shipment_count: int, eta_cal: decimal(10,2), eta_cal_uofm: string, eta_cal_name: string, origin_day_of_week: smallint, eta_head_id: int, exception_reason: string, id: bigint]
```

And I'm trying to merge them, but Spark is complaining that the types are not the same:

```
>>> df_new = df_latest.join(df, on=['id'], how='anti').unionAll(df)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/user_lib_spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1842, in unionAll
    return self.union(other)
  File "/home/ec2-user/user_lib_spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1830, in union
    return DataFrame(self._jdf.union(other._jdf), self.sql_ctx)
  File "/home/ec2-user/user_lib_spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1305, in __call__
  File "/home/ec2-user/user_lib_spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 117, in deco
    raise converted from None
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Union can only be performed on tables with the compatible column types. timestamp <> bigint at the first column of the second table;
'Union false, false
:- Project [id#10L, created_at#0, modified#1, status#2, shipment_count#3, eta_cal#4, eta_cal_uofm#5, eta_cal_name#6, origin_day_of_week#7, eta_head_id#8, exception_reason#9]
:  +- Join LeftAnti, (id#10L = id#42L)
:     :- Relation[created_at#0,modified#1,status#2,shipment_count#3,eta_cal#4,eta_cal_uofm#5,eta_cal_name#6,origin_day_of_week#7,eta_head_id#8,exception_reason#9,id#10L] parquet
:     +- Relation[created_at#32,modified#33,status#34,shipment_count#35,eta_cal#36,eta_cal_uofm#37,eta_cal_name#38,origin_day_of_week#39,eta_head_id#40,exception_reason#41,id#42L] JDBCRelation((select * from public.eta_summary where modified > '2022-03-15'::date) as eta_summary) [numPartitions=8]
+- Relation[created_at#32,modified#33,status#34,shipment_count#35,eta_cal#36,eta_cal_uofm#37,eta_cal_name#38,origin_day_of_week#39,eta_head_id#40,exception_reason#41,id#42L] JDBCRelation((select * from public.eta_summary where modified > '2022-03-15'::date) as eta_summary) [numPartitions=8]
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The solution was to use:

```
df_new = df_latest.join(df, on=['id'], how='anti').unionByName(df)
```

instead of:

```
df_new = df_latest.join(df, on=['id'], how='anti').unionAll(df)
```